# Не работает скрипт сортировки при использовании кириллицы

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть сайт на WP c частично русифицированной темой (Cactus). В частности, помимо неполного перевода, не работает один нужный с точки зрения функционала скрипт сортировки. 

Если вводить значения латиницей - все прекрасно, если же использовать кириллицу - все отображается корректно и по-русски, но кнопки фильтра работать перестают. В коде этот русский текст выглядит крякозябрами такого рода %d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f

Кодировки БД и файлов я проверял - все в utf8.

Подскажите, если кто знает, в чем причина может быть?

Вот кусок кода

```
<nav class="cactus-portfolio-filter">
  <ul>
  <?php  $display_filter = cactus_option('display_filter_'.$cactus_section_key);?>
  <?php if( !empty($tags) && $display_filter == '1' ):?>
    <li class="active"><a href="javascript:;" data-filter="*"><?php _e( 'Все', 'cactus' );?></a></li>
    <?php foreach($tags as $tag){
            echo $tag;
        }
        ?>
        <?php endif;?>
        <li class="gap"></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

А вот скрипт

```
jQuery(window).load(function(e) {

var containerEl = document.querySelector('#<?php echo $id;?>');
var mixer = mixitup(containerEl);
jQuery('.cactus-portfolio-filter').on( 'click', 'a', function() {
    jQuery(this).parents('.cactus-portfolio-filter').find('li').removeClass('active');
    jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Вы не предоставили код. Переформулируйте вопрос.

Comment: Что за тема? Что за плагин? Без этих подробностей вряд ли кто-то сможет помочь.

Comment: Проблема не в кодировке. Вы привели фразу после обработки url_encode()

Comment: Да и вообще, что такое эти $tags откуда берутся в коде нет

Comment: 1. С кириллицей в параметрах и не будет работать в 99% случаев. Просто потому что в УРЛах не бывает кириллицы. Соответственно буржуские скрипты не обязаны понимать и принимать "крокозябы" (многие англоязычные разрабы тупо не думают что где-то может быть по-другому). Плюс к этому что и как получится после перекодирования во многом зависит от сервера. 2 это `_e( 'Все', 'cactus' )` - не перевод, а ересь. https://ru.wordpress.org/support/topic/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD/